# ASP.NET 5 (VNext) Autofac Instance per Request

Tags: asp.net, autofac, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm playing around with ASP.NET vNext and I'd like to utilize `InstancePerRequest` for some of my registrations, e.g `MyDbContext` would be one example.

I've got `Autofac` running using `InstancePerLifetimeScope` for these dependencies. Which works....

But as soon as I change over to use `InstancePerRequest` I get this common error:

> DependencyResolutionException: No scope with a Tag matching
>   'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance
>   was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as
>   per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component
>   (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request
>   dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or
>   ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container
>   itself.

I've read the Autofac help docs around this.... but I'm not sure how to set up the "request lifetime scope" which is causing this exception.

Has anyone set up an ASP.NET 5 web app integrating Autofac including `InstancePerRequest`?

Comment: I haven't try ASP.net v5 with Autofac yet but a common reason for this error is that `HttpContext.Current` is null while resolving. What is the stack trace of the exception ? are you resolving a type outside of a HTTP request ?

Comment: Yeh at runtime it's trying to resolve the per request dependencies against a tagged lifetime scope which is what per request sits on top off. Problem is a lifetime scope hasn't been set yet. I'll put up the stack trace ASAP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options as far as I know and both of them will give you the instance per request.

Assuming you have the below class to register:

```
public class Foo : IDisposable 
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("created");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("disposed");
    }
}
```

#### Register with IServiceCollection

You can register the instance as scoped on `IServiceCollection` and build the Autofac container based on this.

```
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddScoped<Foo, Foo>();

#if DNX451
            // Create the autofac container
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Create the container and use the default application services as a fallback
            AutofacRegistration.Populate(builder, services);
            var container = builder.Build();

            return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
#endif

            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
```

#### Register on Autofac Builder

You can register the type on Autofac builder as instance per lifetime scope and this will give you the instance per request lifetime:

```
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
#if DNX451

            // Create the autofac container
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Create the container and use the default application services as a fallback
            AutofacRegistration.Populate(builder, services);
            builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<Foo>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            var container = builder.Build();

            return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
#endif

            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
```

As said, the result will be the same for both:

[image]

For more info per request instances on ASP.NET 5: [Middlewares and Per Request Dependency Injection](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/exciting-things-about-asp-net-vnext-series-middlewares-and-per-request-dependency-injection)

Comment: Cheers @tugberk.. I thought there would have been a way to explicitly use InstancePerRequest... but if using 'InstancePerLifetimeScope' in this manner is the same thing then that's great.